# File library that help creating paths

Tags: java

I'm looking for a file utilities library that help creating paths, i.e. if I want to create a file in "a/b/c/x/y/z", it will check if each directory exists and creates it if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about reading the [File javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

Specifically, given `File foo` which represents a text file you want to create, you can execute `foo.getParentFile().mkdirs()`.

Answer (score 1):

[File.mkdirs()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())